# Class method can not be found

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have a simple JS class which looks like this:

```
function Connection(){
  this.conn = new WebSocket("ws://my.website:9090");
  this.connection.onmessage = function(message){
    var data = JSON.parse(message.data);

    switch (data.type) {
      case "login":
        this.onLogin(data.success);
        break;
      // removed other cases for brevity
      default:
        console.log("Data from server was not as expected" + JSON.stringify(data));
    }
  }
}
```

Then, I added an `onLogin` method using `prototype`:

```
Connection.prototype.onLogin = function(success) {
  console.log("login, success is " + success);
  $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
}
```

When I created a connection and the server returned `login`, it said `TypeError: this.onLogin is not a function`. I tried putting this `prototype` method before and after the `Connection` class, but that didn't do anything. So, then I tried to move the `onLogin` function into the `Conection` function:

```
function Connection(){
  //same stuff as at top of question
  this.onLogin = function(success) {
    console.log("login, success is " + success);
    $("#loginModal").modal('hide');
  }
}
```

This resulted in the same error. How do I fix this?

Comment: It's easy, it says that "onLogin is not a function", so, check again onLogin function

Comment: you are in a new function, so your context of `this` has changed.

Comment: It'll work if you replace `function(message){` with `(message) => {`

Comment: So you have *two* functions called 'Connection'? Or just one, with the second one being a new attempt at the first?

Comment: @ObsidianAge just one, with the second one being a new attempt.